# Newton's Method to find point on parabola closest to origin

Tags: calculus

Using Newton's Method, find the coordinates accurate to 6 decimal points of the point on the parabola y=(x-1)^2 that is closest to the origin.

Answer (score 2):

use that the distance between two points is given by
$d(P_1,P_2)=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$
let $P_1(0,0)$ and $P_2(x,(x-1)^2)$ then we get 
$d=\sqrt{x^2+(x-1)^4}$
by Newton we get $[ 0.537841448698199387,[x= 0.410245487705493017]]$